# How to view raw yuv files with mplayer?

Tags: linux, yuv, mplayer

As raw viewers like Vooya do not work for me on Mint19, I would like to view these files with mplayer.

Someone on stackoverflow already asked similar questions, but these anwsers do not work for me too, as my YUV files are not I420.

How could I view these volatile format yuv files with mplayer?

Comment: ffmpeg, imagemagick etc can all display raw video. vooya *should* work as well. I managed to get it to work an several systems not officially supported. It usually boils down to finding the right versions of libjpeg and libpng. Ping me if you need any assistance! Mint is debian-based so it shouldn't be any problems...

Comment: @FredrikPihl Thanks man , The Vooya crashed on my Mint19, the backtrace shows it crashed int libproxychains, but actually I did not run vooya in proxychains, have no idea why. I already sent a feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mplayer -demuxer rawvideo -rawvideo w=640:h=480:format=yuy2 my_file.yuyv -loop 0
```

Altered from [here](http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2011/01/view-raw-yuv-file-with-mplayer.html)